# How to create an automatic set of subplots from a looping through a list of dataframe columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, foreach, seaborn

I want to create efficient code in which I can pass a set of dataframe columns to a for-loop or list comprehension and it will return a set of subplots of the same type (one for each variable) depending on the type of matplotlib or seaborn plot I want to use. I'm looking for an approach that is relatively agnostic to the type of graph.

I've only tried to create code using matplotlib. Below, I provide a simple dataframe and the latest code I tried.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2,8,3,4,3], "B": [0, 2,4,8,3,2], "C": [0, 0,7,8,2,1]},
                 index =[1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000] )
df.index.name='Year'

fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=3,figsize=(8,4))
for  yvar in df:
    ts = pd.Series(yvar, index = df.index)
    ts.plot(kind = 'line',ax=axs[i])
    plt.show()
```

I expect to see a subplot for each variable that is passed to the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2,8,3,4,3], "B": [0, 2,4,8,3,2], "C": [0, 0,7,8,2,1]},
                 index =[1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000] )

plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    plt.subplot(1,3,i+1)
    plt.plot(df.index, df[col], label=col)
    plt.xticks(df.index)
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Use `plt.subplot(no_of_rows, no_of_cols, current_subplot_number)` to set the current plotting to a subplot. Any plotting done will go the  `current_subplot_number`.

Answer (score 2):

Loop over both, the columns and the axes simultaneously. Show the plot outside the loop.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=len(df.columns), figsize=(8,4))
for ax, yvar in zip(axs.flat, df):
    df[yvar].plot(ax=ax)
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, you can also directly plot the complete dataframe

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=len(df.columns), figsize=(8,4))
df.plot(subplots=True, ax=axs)
plt.show()
```